# jQuery multiple events including an IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Does anybody know how to combine these two events in jQuery?

The closest I could get was having 2 duplicate scripts that respond to 2 different events, which in my opinion is absolutely terrible. But it's the only way I could think of to do this for now. Both scripts do the exact same thing (or A LOT of things actually). I know jQuery has an option to add multiple event handlers to the same element, but how does this work if one of the events contains an `if` condition?

**This runs when the user clicks on a radio button in a radio group:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // When radio button is clicked
  $("input[name='select']").click(function() {
    var select = $("input[name='select']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "script.class.php",
      data: { select: select },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // A lot of things will happen here...
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  });     
});
```

**This runs IF the radio group already has a radio button selected:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If value is already present
  if ($("input[name='select']:checked").val()) {
    var select = $("input[name='select']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "script.class.php",
      data: { select: select },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // The same things as in the previous script will also happen here...
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing to me. Ignoring the `ready` handlers, there is only one event hander in all this code - it is the `click` event. What does "_these two events_" refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the common code in a function and then call it

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // When radio button is clicked
  $("input[name='select']").click(commonCode);
  if ($("input[name='select']:checked").val()) {
    commonCode();
  }
  function commonCode(){  
    var select = $("input[name='select']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "script.class.php",
      data: { select: select },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // A lot of things will happen here...
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  }     
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution!